# How do I create an ASP.NET MVC wizard with back button support?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an app with ASP.NET MVC and I have the need for a wizard style interface on one of my pages.

Here is what I'm doing so far:
I have created a page with 5 divs.  All have "display: none" set in the css file.  When the user hits the page for the first time, I use jquery to show the first step using:

```
$("#callStep1").show();
```

The first step has a select list and when the user makes a selection the following code is executed:

```
$("#callStep1").hide();
$("#callStep2").show();
```

This continues until the user gets to step 5 and clicks the submit button.  Everything is working fine except if I'm on step 2, 3, 4, 5 and hit the back button, it takes me all the way back to the page I was on before when I really just want to go to the previous step.

How can I make this work?  I've seen some examples using "#" and creating links on the page, but not sure if there is a better way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't absolutely need AJAX on the wizard page, it is possible to do this by returning different views after a successful form POST.

In the controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult DoSomethingLong(int somethingId, int step)
{
  MyModelType myModel = MyModelFactory.Fetch(somethingId);

  switch(step)
  {
    case 1:
      return View("Step1", myModel);
      break;
    case 2:
      return View("Step2", myModel);
      break;
  }
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult DoSomethingLong(int somethingId, int step)
{
   MyModelType myModel = MyModelFactory.Fetch(somethingId);

   if (TryUpdateModel(myModel))
   {
       //Successful update.  Send to next step.
       return RedirectToAction("DoSomethingLong", new {somethingId = somethingId, step = step + 1}
   }
   else
   {
       //Update failed, redisplay current View with validation errors.
       return View(myModel);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Implement Ajax driven links in a
>   completely unobtrusive and accessible
>   manner (also known as Hijax) with
>   support for the browser's back/forward
>   navigation buttons and bookmarking.
>   Enhance comparable DHTML driven links
>   as well.

http://www.stilbuero.de/jquery/history/#Chapter_3

[Hijax (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hijax)

Comment: The link's rotten, somebody throw some fruit fresh on it.